# iOS: UIWebView full open source browser?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

Does anyone know if there are any open source solutions out there that use UIWebview to build a full browser?  There is something like this in Three20 when you pass a URL, but I am assuming there must be other alternatives out there.

I realize that UIWebView is a web browser, but hooking up refresh, back button, URL bar, etc will take extra time.

Suggestions?

Comment: UIWebView is a full browser, as stated in the answer. that said, I've been working on a user script wrapper [which can be seen on GitHub](github.com/mosheBerman/Fahrii/).

Comment: I realize that.  Looking for something built with back button, URL bar, refresh etc. already built.

Comment: take a peek at the docs. Most of what you want sounds like it is supported by UIWebView methods. There's no known (as of now) prebuilt project like that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[SVWebViewController](https://github.com/samvermette/SVWebViewController) looks pretty much like what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

I have started an open source project (MIT License) to make something as close as possible to the native MobileSafari application (on iPhone and iPad).

Here are the features so far :

- Design close to Mobile Safari (iOS 4.x) native application (for both iPhone and iPad)
- Bookmark support (support for folders in bookmarks not implemented yet)
- Mail link support
- Print web page support
- Long tap handling (open or copy link) with customizable menu

Anyone wanting to contribute to this project is welcome to do it !

You can clone/fork the project here : https://github.com/sylverb/CIALBrowser

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/ghostery/banshee

**EDIT** the project is now maintained here: https://github.com/acatighera/banshee

It's an open source browser with tabs, bookmarks, search, etc.

[image]

Comment: This shows 'Cannot Connect' for any URL. Any updates ?

Answer (score 3):

`UIWebView` is a full browser ! To open a url in `webView` you do this -

```
NSURL *url        = [NSURL URLWithString:webAddress];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:req];
```

You can even [insert javascript](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/how-to-inject-javascript-functions-into-a-uiwebview) into `UIWebView`. You could customize it to your liking.

```
//To customize the look & feel...
self.webView.scalesPageToFit     = YES;
self.webView.autoresizingMask    = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
self.webView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

//To insert Javascript
NSString *jsCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = 0.5;"];
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCommand];
```

You could do lot more. Have fun...

**UPDATE:** To get a back button and all, `webView` provides those features, back, forward etc. all those browser features. You need to code up the buttons & UI & for code you could do this -

```
-(IBAction)goForward:(id)sender
{
    [webView goForward];
}

-(IBAction)goBack:(id)sender
{
    [webView goBack];
}

-(IBAction) gotoHome:(id)sender
{
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://google.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Comment: I realize that.  Looking for something built with back button, URL bar, refresh etc. already built.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check out KINWebBrowser, a drop in web browser module for your apps.
https://github.com/dfmuir/KINWebBrowser

Features

- iOS 7 & 8 support for iPhone and iPad
- Customizable UI
- Portrait and landscape orientation support
- Use with existing UINavigationController or present modally
- Load URL from NSURL or NSString
- Delegate protocol for status callbacks
- Action button to allow users to copy URL, share, or open in Safari & Google Chrome
- Supports subclassing
- Installation with CocoaPods